# RSelenium in Docker container on GitHub Actions ubuntu runner/vm

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, github-actions, rselenium

I am trying to run an RSelenium script in a Docker container on a GitHub Actions runner/VM. The runner installs Ubuntu, starts a Docker container, installs R, and required packages.

However, I am running into an issue that I cannot resolve.

**Workflow File (main.yml):**

```yaml
# main.yml
name: Selenium Test

# Controls when the action will run.
on:
  push:
    branches: main

jobs:
  testFlow:
    # The type of OS
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Set up Docker
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Start Selenium Docker container
        run: |
          docker run -d -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome:latest

      # Load repo and install R
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2

      - name: Install libcurl
        run: sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
      - name: Install renv 0.9.2
        run: Rscript -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/renv_0.9.2.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')"
      - name: Install rcmdcheck 1.3.3
        run: Rscript -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rcmdcheck_1.3.3.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')"

      - name: Install packages
        run: |
          R -e 'install.packages("rvest")'
          R -e 'install.packages("RSelenium")'

      # Run R script
      - name: Script
        run: Rscript test.r
```

However, it begins running the R script (test.r) below:

**R Script (test.r):**

```r
# Load the required libraries
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

# Step 2: Start server
print("Starting remoteDriver")

remDR <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
                                 port = 4444L,
                                 browserName = "chrome")
Sys.sleep(15)
print("Opening browser")
remDR$open()
print("Driver opened")
Sys.sleep(15)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------#####

# Navigate to the website
remDR$navigate("https://cran.r-project.org/")

# Wait
Sys.sleep(5)
```

It cuts out and I get the following error:
[Error message on GitHub Actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14xQ.png)

```
Run Rscript test.r
  
[1] "Starting remoteDriver"
[1] "Opening browser"
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
$id
[1] NA

[1] "Driver opened"
NULL
Error: Error in .self$value[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
Calls: <Anonymous>
Execution halted
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I can't figure out why because it works locally but will not work in the GitHub actions workflow. Can anyone help or advise where I am going wrong please?

I have tried setting up an ubuntu VM + docker & running a selenium image within the R script. It did not work.

Comment: When you say "it works locally", do you mean "in a Docker container that runs locally on your mashine" or does it mean "it runs locally on your OS"?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I mean that it runs in a Docker container directly on my machine (windows).

Comment: Is that script complete? Looks like it doesn't have the statement causing that "subscript out of bounds" error after `navigate` call. Can you please confirm? Thanks!